# InputLayers and Cocos2d

Tags: cocos2d-iphone, box2d

I am using tags to pass references around my two main layers, basically having a Hud layer and a game layer. However, my Hud needs multiple tags to be passed to the main game layer, for example, the joystick controller and two buttons. How can I go about doing this? Perhaps I can make an array of tags from the HUD and pass that to the main layer?

Thank you.

Comment: You could set up a delegate system for your input layer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I made the joystick and buttons CCTouchDelegates, allowing touches to be passed around.